# Cloudboost - Register User Error

Tags: cloudboost

I'm using the example from your quickstart section on your website to register a user, problem is, it is throwing back an error. Did I miss something? See below for the error.

Error: Request failed with status code 400 -
https://api.cloudboost.io/user/ohoydfjlnmnf/signup

```
CB.CloudApp.init('ohoydfjlnmnf', '********-3*9b-4**b-9***-a**b**2**5*1');

//Registration
var user = new CB.CloudUser();

user.set('username', 'NEWUSER');
user.set('password', 'PASSWORD');
user.set('email', 'EMAILADDRESS');

user.signUp({
    success: function(user) {
        //Registration successfull
        console.log(user);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        //Error in user registration.
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: You would be signing up a user with the same email.

Comment: @Nawaz-CloudBoost.io : The error as mentioned in my question is, Error: Request failed with status code 400 - https://api.cloudboost.io/user/ohoydfjlnmnf/signup . I'm not sure what you mean by the same email, I've tried multiple.

Comment: No that's the code of the request. Can you check the error message by going into your Network tab in Chrome and looking at the response payload.

Comment: Ah, alright the payload contained information that helped me correct the problem, it was a column name problem. Thank you.